# Get extension from an incomplete filename

Tags: c#, .net

I have a path without an extension given:

```
C:\myFilename
```

How do I know what is the extension of this file? Is there a easier (and less intensive) way apart from looping the entire directory and see which one matches to the string I have?

Comment: The path does not contain the extension, so if it's meant to refer an existing file, you *have* to get the extension by searching for the matching file. You can do that by looping the directory, or for example by reading the directory into a Dictionary<string,string> first.

Comment: looks like I have to do it that way. Was hoping to avoid it as I would think the cpu resources needed to loop through thousands of file in this way can be quite alot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many files with same filename with different extensions in the same Directory:

```
//Get all the files starting from myFilename
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "myFilename.*");

//Use Path.GetExtenstion() method to extract extension part 
foreach(string file in files)
{
   extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
   Console.WriteLine("Extension of ('{0}') is '{1}'",  file, extension);
}
```

[**Path Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path_methods.aspx) has some very useful methods.

```
Path.GetDirectoryName()
Path.GetFileName()
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()
Path.GetFullPath() 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Define your incomplete path in `Directory.GetFiles()`'s `searchPattern` parameter with `*` at the end
2. Iterate over all matched file paths and get their file name and extension with `Path.GetFileName()` and `Path.GetExtension()`

   ```
   string searchPattern = "myFilename*";
   string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles (@"C:\", searchPattern);

   foreach (string filePath in filePaths) {
       string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
       string ext = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\","myFilename*")
```

will return an array of all filenames matching the pattern, without you having to loop it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, ideally your program will be expecting a limited list of extensions. Using those extension you can directly access the file. But if you dont know then you can get only those files which meets the regular expression filename.* , where * will be any sequence of characters after .

Here is a sample code to do this

```
String[] FileList = GetFiles("c:\MyFileName*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

You will also find 2 more variants of this function which will give you recursive search and other options

You may want to read this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx